# Updating Entity Framework 6.0.2 to 6.1.3 fails when mapping entities mapped to the same table name but in different scheme

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, database-schema

I have a project that uses entity framework (EF) 6.0.2 which is currently in use. I used for my entities code-first and custom maps. After upgrade to EF 6.1.3 while trying to run the project it shows me the following error:

> The entity types 'StoreAuditLog' and 'Store' cannot share table
>   'Stores' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not
>   have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary
>   keys between them.

The corresponding mappings for these entities are:

```
public class StoreAuditLogMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<StoreAuditLog>
{
    public StoreAuditLogMap()
    {
        // ... Removed for simplicity

        ToTable("Stores", "audit");
    }
}

public class StoreMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Store>
{
    public StoreMap()
    {
        //... Removed for simplicity

        ToTable("Stores");
    }
}
```

which function properly using the 6.0.2 version of EF. The entities do not have any relationship between each other.

According to the documentation of the EF, the ToTable("tableName") method creates the tables in
schema "dbo". But if I do not specify the schema "dbo" in StoreMap the error occurs

Is this some bug of EF 6.1.3? Why the code works correctly using the version 6.0.2 of EF? EF should not continue creating Store table in schema "dbo" as it does in version 6.0.2? Why do I have to modify the mapping to pass a value that is supposed to be the default?